# Need something like static inheritance in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, static

I'm having a small design issue and wanted to consult. 
Lets say we have the following class hierarchy:

```
abstract class A
{
}

class B : A
{
}

class C: A
{
}
```

I want that both B and C have a certain field x so that it's value is different between the classes but shared among all instances of the same class (i.e: if b1, b2 are instances of B and c1,c2 instances of C then b1.x = b2.x and c1.x = c2.x and b1.x != c1.x).
Is there an elegant way to do this by taking advantage of the fact that both B, C derive from the same base class or do I have to create a static field x in both classes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: small correction, of course I meant b1.x != c1.x.

Comment: It's your own question, you should be able to edit it without any reputation requirement.

Comment: You're right of course, I missed the edit tag, sorry.

Comment: No need to apologize, you're new here.

Answer (score 4):

You mean like this?

```
abstract class A
{
    static Dictionary<Type, int> all_x;
    protected int X {
        get { return all_x[GetType()]; }
        set { all_x[GetType()] = value; }
    }
}
```

---

If it has to be a field so you can pass by reference:

```
abstract class A
{
    class SharedType { int x; }
    static Dictionary<Type, SharedType> all_shared;
    protected SharedType Shared {
        get
        {
            Type t = GetType();
            SharedType result;
            if (!all_shared.TryGetValue(t, out result) {
                 result = new SharedType();
                 all_shared.Add(t, result);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Also, we can improve performance by doing the lookup only once per instance:

```
abstract class A
{
    class SharedType { int x; }
    static Dictionary<Type, SharedType> all_shared;
    protected SharedType Shared;
    A() {
        Type t = GetType();
        if (!all_shared.TryGetValue(t, out Shared) {
             Shared = new SharedType();
             all_shared.Add(t, Shared);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought of that option but I hoped there was something better. Thank you.

Comment: @Marina: What didn't you like about it?  There are some tricks that can be used to make it faster (on average), or have a real "field" that you can pass by reference, but they also add complexity.

Comment: I haven't tried it but I think this solution has an issue with inheritance. Let's say B derives from A and D derives from B. Then I would expect that B.x == D.x but in this case the values would be different

Comment: @Victor: Then you are I are reading the question differently, because my understanding is that @Marina wants `B` and `D` to have separate copies of `x`, since they are different classes.  But there's a lot of ambiguity in the question.  Perhaps it's the case that member functions of `D` should use `xd` and member functions of `B` should use `xb`, without regard for the dynamic type of the object.  Can't tell until @Marina clarifies.

Comment: Speed is one issue (I'm writing a graphics application and this would be called for every instance of a geometric primitive on every draw call). It's not that I don't like it, I just hoped that there might be some nifty feature of C# I don't know about that enables this scenario.

Comment: @Marina: If the value depends on the actual object type, then I don't think you can do better performance-wise than my third code snippet.

Comment: If you want speed, then you should write that little bit of code in every class that will make it compiler-happy. Its not that much really. And I think I saw exactly same question here some time back..

Comment: @Euphoric: If you mean creating a static field in both classes, that won't have what I understand to be the desired effect... you can't even refer to `b1.x` and `b2.x` let alone have `a => a.x` return different results depending on whether `b1` or `c1` is passed in.  But my interpretation of the question could be wrong.

Comment: I never said it would be enough. If you want to access this value from instances instead from type, you should create abstract property, that would allow access to this static field from instance and override it in every class.

Comment: @Euphoric: I haven't profiled, but I believe that my third snippet will be faster than a virtual property.  Indirection through a data pointer is generally faster than an indirect function call, because there's no unpredicted branching (and corresponding pipeline stall).  But if performance is that important a profiler should definitely be used.  The main reason for my approach is that it minimizes the amount of code, thus should be more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do this is if you make class A a generic class, i.e. class `A<T>`.  Then have class B implement a different type for the generic type than the generic type that Class C implements.

If you don't use generics, then I believe this is impossible in .NET.

Here is an example where lets say the value you were interested in was a data structure with members int Foo and string Bar.  One derive class could implement the an identical structure (but different derived type) than the other - the two structures would implement the same interface.

```
interface IAvalue
    {
        int Foo { get; set;}
        string Bar {get; set;}
    }

    struct BValue
        : IAvalue
    {

        public int Foo { get; set; }
        public string Bar { get; set; }
    }

    struct CValue
        : IAvalue
    {
        public int Foo { get; set; }
        public string Bar { get; set; }


    }

    abstract class A<T> where T : IAvalue
    {
        protected static T myValue;
    }

    class B : A<BValue>
    {
        static B()
        {
            myValue.Foo = 1;
            myValue.Bar = "text1";
        }
    }

    class C : A<CValue>
    {
        static C()
        {
            myValue.Foo = 2;
            myValue.Bar = "text2";
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is making each class have a different data type for myValue (or 'x' in the author's question) instead of just a different value. One side effect is the value will be different, but I don't think the author intended to use two different data types, even if there is some compatibility between int and long.

Comment: I edited my answer that might be slightly more acceptable - share the same interface

Comment: It's a bit more abstracted now and still the same concept of varying the data type for the base field. There is now implicit compatibility through a shared data type - the interface.

Comment: As @Euphoric pointed out elsewhere, the author indicates she wants the resolution in the base class: `Is there an elegant way to do this by taking advantage of the fact that both B, C derive from the same base class` By the time the author creates an interface, the supporting structures and additionally adds generics to each derived class, it has somewhat defeated the purpose. In that case she might as well just simply put a static field on each derived class to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

What should those values be for the field x? If you need to specify that the value of x for A should be "a", the value of x for B should be "b" etc., then you will have to specify the values "a", "b", ... somewhere and then you mught as well just use:

```
abstract class A {
    public static int x = 1;    // Just using "int" as example.
}

class B : A {
    public static int x = 2;
}
```

If you do not care what the values are (which type do you need then) but merely want the values to be "different", then instead of using fields you could use something like:

```
abstract class A {
    public int X { get { return this.GetType().GetHashCode(); } }
}
```

This does not take hash collisions into account, but maybe it is useful anyway?

What is it you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

To build on Ben Voigt's first answer, I think what you want for your base class is this:

```
public abstract class A
    {
        private static ConcurrentDictionary<Type, int> _typeIDs = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, int>();
        private static int _nextID = 1;

        public int TypeID
        {
            get
            {
                return _typeIDs.GetOrAdd(this.GetType(), type => System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref _nextID));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract int Value { get; }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override int Value { get { return 1; } }
}

public class C : A
{
    public override int Value { get { return 2; } }
}
```

Comment: If this author's field has an unchanging value (and she didn't specify in the original question) then this will work to return a distinct value per class.

Comment: -1. autor doesnt want constants. And he wants to resolve it only in class A. So no aditional code in B and C.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one .net feature: If you have static data members in a generic class, .net creates different instances of static data members for each generic type you use.

So, you can write:

```
public abstract class A<T> where T : A<T>
{
    protected static int myVariable { get; set; }
}
```

And inherit your classes as:

```
public class B : A<B>
{
    public B()
    {
        myVariable = 1;
    }
    public int GetVariable()
    {
        return myVariable;
    }
}

public class C : A<C>
{
    public C()
    {
        myVariable = 2;
    }
    public int GetVariable()
    {
        return myVariable;
    }
}
```

Then every instance of `B` will have shared access to one instance of `myVariable` and every instance of `C` will have shared access to another.

So, if you add `Set(int a)` method:

```
public void Set(int a)
{
    myVariable = a;
}
```

And run the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    B b1 = new B();
    C c1 = new C();
    B b2 = new B();
    C c2 = new C();

    Console.Write("{0}; ", b1.GetVariable());  // 1
    Console.Write("{0}; ", b2.GetVariable());  // 1
    Console.Write("{0}; ", c1.GetVariable());  // 2
    Console.Write("{0}; ", c2.GetVariable());  // 2

    Console.WriteLine();

    c2.Set(333);

    Console.Write("{0}; ", b1.GetVariable());  // 1
    Console.Write("{0}; ", b2.GetVariable());  // 1
    Console.Write("{0}; ", c1.GetVariable());  // 333
    Console.Write("{0}; ", c2.GetVariable());  // 333

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

You get: `1; 1; 2; 2;`
`1; 1; 333; 333;` output.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest defining a static Dictionary<Type, Integer[]>, and having the base-class constructor call GetType() on itself and see if it's yet in the static dictionary.  If not, create a new single-element array and store it in the dictionary.  Otherwise grab the array from the dictionary and store it in an instance field.  Then define a property which reads or writes element zero of the array.  This approach will achieve the requested semantics for all derivatives and sub-derivatives of the class.